# Append numbers to input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to copy numbers from package-size div between "/" and "pcs" characters and paste them to input value. In this case number is 100. Is that possible?

Following code works if we have only numbers inside package-size div.

How about if I have multiple product divs?

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="package-size">1/100 pcs.</div>
  <input type="number" value="1" />
</div>

$( ".package-size" ).val(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
```

**Update 1:**

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="package-size">
    <p>1/100 pcs.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="number" value="1" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2:**

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="package-size">
    <p>1/100 pcs.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="number" value="1" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <div class="package-size">
    <p>200 pcs.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="number" value="1" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `div` does not have a `.val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the input element using relative positioning

```
$(".package-size").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).next("input").val(text.match(/\/(\d+)/)[1]);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bRGYf/)

Comment: Just noticed that my input-field is wrapped with multiple divs and solution doesn't work anymore. I tried `.parents()` and `.parent()` but it didn't help. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Really appreciate, works great! One more challenge occurred when testing this. Sometimes package size is just `100 pcs` instead of `1/100 pcs`. I posted update 2 above. Do you have any idea is that possible to get work?

Comment: Can you still help me on these? Here is my CodePen. 
http://codepen.io/morteymor/pen/FgIhs

I want to target numbers that have slash ”/”. In those cases I want to grab the number before slash and copy it into the next input filed. E.g. on here 2/500 pcs. I’d like to copy number 2.

Comment: @Aleksi it will be better if you can post it as a new question and post back the link here...

Comment: Great, thanks! You are awesome! And thanks for the tip, I'll make a new question next time.